# Как реализовать добавление элементов на страницу в реальном времени в ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Например, на странице есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую на страницу должен добавиться textbox. Причем сколько раз на кнопку нажмешь столько textbox'ов появится. Что для этого надо изучить/почитать?

Comment: *Что для этого надо изучить/почитать?* – JavaScript

Comment: @АндрейNOP <- этот парень прав